# How to update an Azure Database from Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, azure-database-mysql

I created a database using Entity Framework (Web Api), but I made some changes, so I would like to update my database.

I think I need to do a migration, but I do not know what else I need to do, because I have already done that but the changes don't appear.

Comment: What do you mean by "update", exactly? e.g. updating **data** with `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/MERGE` or **changing the database's design/schema**? (e.g. `CREATE TABLE`, `ALTER TABLE`, `DROP VIEW` etc?

Comment: I added a column in the Model, so the database needs to be updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the applied migrations are not loading correctly to your DB, you can update it manually and delete all the migrations you have.